# math.SE and Winter Bash 2013

Tags: discussion, poll, winter-bash

> ***Note:*** See [robjohn's answer below](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11827/8348) for the surprising result.
>
> Thanks to everyone for voicing their opinions!

---

As the year draws to a close, the Stack Exchange network is planning another [Winter Bash](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/12/welcome-to-winter-bash-2012/).

> ## Some Details
>
> - Winter Bash is an annual event that can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users earn “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar can “wear”.
> - This event will run from **16 December 2013 to 3 January 2014**. Users will be able to see their entire hat collection at http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.
> - Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available.
> - At the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.
>
> The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

In the past, math.SE has not opted to join this event. This year we want to get input from the community. Just vote on whether you wish math.SE to participate in this event, and $$\huge\color{#000000}{\textbf{please do not downvote these answers.}}$$

We have until **1 December 2013** to inform the Stack Exchange team whether we wish to participate (otherwise they will assume we don't).

Comment: Are there any other options other than the two below? I feel like my excluded middle is being left out.

Comment: @copper.hat: As long as I'm a moderator here ***we will*** obey _tertium non datur_!!  I shall have none of your intuitionistic insolence!!

Comment: On with the fun, so!

Comment: Arthur: You should have written that you will not have people not following the LEM while you're a moderator. :-)

Comment: I like fun, but we resist asking people to click through.  I had to click through to find out what this was about, then again to search for what a gravatar (and the spell checker refuses this word) is.  How can my gravatar (one of the symmetric square patterns) wear a hat, glasses or whatever?  Call me a Grinch.

Comment: Which tasks users will have to accomplish to receive hats? Is the set of tasks the same for all Stack Exchange sites, or it can be customised? If we may have tasks that will help e.g. [to reduce the unanswered queue](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141/the-crusade-of-answers), then why not to join?

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: I am almost certain that the tasks (and hats) will be uniform across the SE network. The details of these tasks have not been released to even the lowly moderators, but there should be a mixture of helpful tasks, and some more or less random tasks (last year posting or voting on 21 Dec earned you an "And I Feel Fine" hat).

Comment: @ArthurFischer thanks for details. It looks like at least it will make no harm, and may even help, so +1 for "Yes".

Comment: And so it begins!

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/winter-bash-2013-is-here/

Comment: "At the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage."  I'm assuming this not only means you can no longer earn hats, but also hats that you have earned will be deleted, correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## We're in!

I have informed the StackExchange team that we wish to participate in the Winter Bash. Find a comfortable snow bank for cover!

Comment: If I understand the badge description correctly, if this answer gets 10 upvotes, Arthur Fischer will get 2 [populist badges](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/39/populist). I think we should try to do it.

Comment: @MartinSleziak No, one doesn't get Populist for answers to own questions. [Source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#68258)

Comment: Oh, it's a pitty! :-( But it's interesting to know anyway.

Comment: @Martin: From an experiment we had on this meta some time ago only the top voted answer gets a Populist.

Comment: I'd just like to say.... I had no idea mods could lock individual answer! Good to know.

Comment: @DanielRust: I think it is _extremely_ rare that anyone would lock an individual answer.  I thought this was a good way to retain the votes (although a couple seem to have snuck in before I remembered that I actually could do this).  My original intention was to simply lock the question, but when I saw robjohn's answer I simply had to allow it to accumulate _some_ votes.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: the code seems to reflect what we've been told. Arthur Fischer did not get a Populist badge when this answer got 11 votes.

Answer (score 59):

## Yes!!!

math.SE should surely join in on this fun!

<sub>[Downvoting this answer will cause ZFC to be inconsistent.]</sub>

Comment: *twitch* ...Must avoid downvote... *twitch*

Comment: Not letting us downvote denies the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: @robjohn: Arthur has joined my programme against choice!

Comment: @Asaf You might want to carefully inspect the answer you are referring to....

Comment: @Lord_Farin After posting I realised that the the footnote might have the absolute opposite effect as what I wished.  So far, so good. [jinx]

Comment: @Arthur: Yes, you have joined the Dark Side. If asked, you didn't have a choice. :-)

Comment: Hm. Someone downvoted. Couldn't they wait until I got my Ph.D. and a tenured position before causing all of my work to be inconsistent and moot?? :-(

Comment: [Adds 'I don't care' vote - *Downvoting this answer will cause $P=NP$.*]

Comment: *Downvoting this comment will end world hunger for ever.*

Comment: @Asaf: I blame the category theorists, myself.

Comment: @Brian: I blame the type theorists, from which there are apparently many in recent times.

Comment: Wow, this conversation is so pointless.

Comment: Apparently, more people want ZFC to be inconsistent rather than the Riemann Hypothesis to be false... :)

Comment: @anorton: It could be that the ***literacy rate*** is higher among those that want RH to be false as compared to those that want $\mathsf{ZFC}$ to be inconsistent.

Comment: Congrats on the great answer badge :P

Answer (score 21):

## No!!!

mathematics is serious business, and so is math.SE!

<sub>[Downvoting this answer will ensure that Riemann's Hypothesis is false.]</sub>

Comment: That would be awesome. We can write a joint paper and get the Fields medal and a million dollars!! If only I haven't upvoted this question I would have instantly downvoted it.

Comment: I voted for this option for reasons of self moderation -- I know I should spend those hours on other things than gathering digital hats.

Comment: Apparently someone wants RH to be false. (Not me though)

Comment: Other things? Like gathering digital badges? ;)

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please contact me about writing that prize winning paper! :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Who would have thought that a [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/s3ObR.png) is worth a million dollars?!

Answer (score 3):

They're heeerreeeee...

It should be pointed that the recent top-bar altering scripts are incompatible with the hats button. If you are interested in hiding the hats, or following your progress you will have to disable it (for the time being).

Comment: where's your hat? :P

Comment: Me? I hate hats. Or generally "happy happy community games". The whole thing really makes me feel physically ill, and it's a great thing that they allow users like me to hide that abominable thing and just forget that it ever existed.