# Would you like some hats? Yes, please!

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

> Due to overwhelming support in favour of participating in Winter Bash 2014, I have informed SE that we're in. (I've locked the two poll answers to preserve the vote totals as they stand now for future reference.)

So... Stack Exchange is planning another [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/). Last year [math.SE joined in the fun for the first time](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11706/8348). Whether it was successful or not, one thing is certain: ***THERE WERE HATS!!!***

As always, even if math.SE doesn't opt out,<sup>1</sup> individual users can still use the "I hate hats" option to hide the inanity.

The event will run between **15 December 2014 and 4 January 2015**. There will be new hats and extra features to keep things fresh. On 5 January, all the hats will go back into storage for another year.

So, I ask again: **Would you like some hats?**

(SE would like to be informed of our decision before 1 December 2014. This will stay open until one option comes out as a clear favourite, or until 1 December, whichever comes first.)

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Okay, there is a difference: this year all sites are considered to be participating unless they inform SE otherwise.</sub>

Comment: Wow! What nice pictures for the poll options.

Comment: Add not to downvote answers :)

Comment: @Hippalectryon: Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: I hate being identified with Poincare. Can I choose [this Hilbert](https://www.marxists.org/glossary/people/h/pics/hilbert.jpg) instead?

Comment: (Also, ugh, not this again. `:(`)

Comment: I hope we don't get this again. We've had it one too many times.

Comment: @GitGud You may be understandably tired of it, but about 38% of current users joined the site after last year's bash was over. They never had one.

Comment: Note that both [these guys](http://www.nooooooooooooooo.com/vader.jpg) are wearing kind of hats.

Comment: @Asaf: Is that some sort of half-Goodwin?

Comment: Arthur, "Any long enough discussion will include at least two photos of Hilbert"?

Comment: I do not need a silly hat, / or any other kind; / I’m really more than certain that / ’Twould just weigh on my mind.

Comment: What if we vote up both answers?

Comment: @EpicGuy: That would be equivalent to upvoting skullpatrol's answer.

Comment: @Nick this is not a given; IMO for this type of question a "no" should count more than a "yes."

Comment: @quid: I am interested in the reasoning behind your comment, though I'm not certain if here is the right place. When awake I'm often at least lurking in TL.

Comment: @quid: Unfortunately, you'll have to count each "No" three times in order to meet demand. And while I might have supported a system in which my vote is binding regardless of anything, I don't think that most people agree. And frankly, I am not sure that I want such system (if it is only limited to this website). So how many "Yes" votes each "No" is going to cancel out?

Comment: Briefly, first the WB is a deviation from the usual (even without clear motivation) and thus should only happen if there is signifcant support. Second, and more importantly, and here the "no" should count more than the "yes" was an oversimplification, I believe that a sentiment of being against this might in some cases be stronger, or more serious, than a sentiment being in favor of this.

Comment: In that sense it could be relevant to know why somebody is against this or in favor of it. By analogy, if a group of people wants to decide on a place to eat, between two possibilities A/B,  I think it makes sense  to also take into account why somebody might prefer one over the other and not just vote. Because, I might just have a slight preference of A over B for some almost random reasons, while somebody else might not find anything on the menu of A that they feel comfortable to eat. (To be clear this is quite general  reasoning I have nothing much against that WB personally)  [ @Asaf ]

Comment: @quid: Thanks. Although it took me a moment to understand WB as "Winter Bash" and not as "White Balance". Your reasoning sounds fairly reasonable. I know that I voted no because I hate "fun" (with the quotation marks, I am a fan of fun in general), and I view this bash as a "fun" activity. Not as bad as that horrible "Battle of the Sites" idea from way back, but still not great. (And hey, not to mention offensive to the southern hemisphere!)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

## YES!!

This guy wore hats, and he turned out okay:

[image]

Comment: Will this particular hat be available?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: The only way to find out is to participate! (Seriously, only the SE employees know for certain what treats are in the works for Winter Bash '14.)

Comment: This is my second-favorite mathematical hat.  My favorite is [this one](http://a.pomf.se/zomyhm.jpg).

Comment: Strictly speaking, we only know this guy wore *half* of a hat - we can't see that that hat has a back side!

Comment: @MJD: Euler in his later days went blind. I think he didn't know that he was really wearing his shirt on his head.

Comment: All we know is that he may have worn half of a hat and that he's dead. Better not take our chances.

Answer (score 19):

## NO!!

Serious mathematicians like this guy would never be caught in a crazy cap:

[image]

Comment: Serious mathematicians wear evil-villain glasses? They must have an amzing sense of fashion to realize that hats will class their style :D

Comment: I wonder how many voted up this just for the coolness of the picture.