# 'Tis the season to be...

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, poll

## ...wearing your hat!

December is just around the corner, and that means that a few annual traditions will soon be here. One, of course, is [Kwanzaa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kwanzaa). Another is Stack Exchange's **Winter Bash**!

For those who don't know what I'm taking about, here's a brief overview:

> Winter Bash is an annual event that can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users have fun by earning “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (very similar to badges).

Math.SE has participated in [the](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11706) [last](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17368) [three](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22113) Winter Bashes. Some of our users have even been pretty successful at it.

This year's event will run from **19 December 2016** until (and including) **8 January 2017**, when all hats go back into storage. Keep an eye out on [winterbash2016.stackexchange.com](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/) for more information, and eventually a hat leaderboard.

As in previous years, math.se will be participating unless your friendly neighbourhood <s>overlords</s> moderators inform Stack Exchange otherwise. We won't do this unless there is considerable community consensus that this event is not wanted here, and this must be done by **13 December 2016**.

In case we're in, but *you* personally want to avoid hats, there will be an "**I hate hats**" button in the footer, which will allow you to be blissfully unaware of (most of) the hat shenanigans.

So...

### should math.se have hats?

Comment: "In case we're in, but you personally want to avoid hats, there will be an "I hate hats" button in the footer, which will allow you to be blissfully unaware of (most of) the hat shenanigans". Good, good.

Comment: I might be a bit late with this, but there are actually three options for hats. See this answer on meta.SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270518. The current answers give only choice between 1) and 3).

Comment: @wythagoras I believe that third option is only available on SO. At least it is never mentioned in the emails that get sent out to the moderators of other sites.

Comment: @arjafi I see. I left a comment on that answer asking about it. I personally would vote for that option if it were available.

Comment: @arjafi It is actually possible. See the latest comment by balpha on the answer I linked.

Comment: I despise all activities which promote extreme gamification of the system *on a network-wide scale*. We've seen enough crap from one user who decided he wants to be the very best on all sites on the network. We don't need concentrated three weeks of people from other sites coming in just to increase their hat counters. It's enough they skew the votes on badly written popular questions.

Comment: Just Kwanza? I hate to be politically incorrect (just kidding, it's actually a breath of fresh air), but how about Hanukkah and Christmas? :)

Comment: They're hereeeeee...

Answer (score 88):

## Of course we want hats!

[image: Emmy Noether wearing a blue fedora]

Like [Emmy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmy_Noether), we know that wearing a hat is ideal!

<sub>Base photograph of Emmy Noether copyright Universitäts-Archiv Göttingen; found in the [Oberwolfach Photo Collection](http://owpdb.mfo.de/detail?photo_id=9267).</sub>

Comment: I just want to say that it was hard only upvoting one answer due to the excellent puns. The "no hats" one took longer to sink in for me personally.

Comment: Perhaps it's just a Noetherian ideal?

Comment: With that in mind, I must say: hats off to you for these excellent puns.

Comment: You hat to say that.

Comment: What a very interesting read.  Its rather strange sometimes how, especially when reading wikipedia, the effect it has by sucking you into very interesting information about someone you once knew nothing about or maybe you just read the name before.  I for one thank you simply for posting her wikipedia page.  I was familiar with Tsen's theorem only from a book I read a long time ago about Fermats Enigma and some related stuff pertaining to fermats last theorem.  But I never knew he was her student!

Answer (score 16):

## Hats are not wanted here!

[image: Emmy Noether not wearing a hat]

Like [Emmy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmy_Noether), we feel that being without a hat ought to be conserved!

<sub>Photograph of Emmy Noether copyright Universitäts-Archiv Göttingen; found in the [Oberwolfach Photo Collection](http://owpdb.mfo.de/detail?photo_id=9267).</sub>

Comment: Hat-haters gonna hat-hate.

Comment: Oh, @rschwieb, I thought that hat-haters gonna hate hats?

Comment: @amWhy hat-hate is a special kind of hate so bizarre and extreme that can't be merely an application of regular hate. Hence: hat-hate

Comment: I know I hate hat-hair, the result of wearing a hat of any kind, so I kinda get where you're going: I developed hat-hate after too many episodes of bad hat-hair!

Comment: But I realize my hat-hate due to hat-hair shouldn't infringe on the rights of those who have developed both a love for hats, and for some, hat-love, to wear the hats of their choices. We need to be careful that our hat-hate doesn't discriminate against those who choose to wear hats.